# How to fix this kitchen disposal which leaks at the top and is not attached correctly?

Tags: garbage-disposal

I had a handiman install a garbage disposal and it worked for a few months but now it is leaking.

How might I go about fixing this installation? (See right and left side photos.)

Is the hanging paper related to the leaking? (See third photo.)

[image: right side][image: left side][image: hanging_patch_square]

Comment: Hire a professional and have it installed properly. Then send the bill to the handyman. He probably will not pay it but it may shake him up and help him he did some shoddy work. You could also take it to small claims court.

Comment: The "paper" is acoustic damping used to lessen the ringing when tapping the sink - basically a sheet of tar. You could glue it back on so it can do its job better.

Answer (score 3):

Your drain flange has cracked and can be seen in the second photo. The mounting bracket should have three screws and only has two and they are lose. The handyman didn't install the new drain flange and bracket but just attached the disposal to the old stuff. This is definitely causing the leak.
You'll need to remove the disposal and then replace the drain flange and mounting bracket and then reattach the disposal. You might have to contact the manufacturer to get the new parts. New parts would have come with the new disposal so maybe the handyman left them with you. You could also try a plumbing supply store.

If you're not familiar with installing disposals you might want to have a pro do it because if not done totally correct, it will leak again.

Comment: Is the flange part of the disposal that might be covered by a warranty?

Comment: The flange and bracket would probably be covered if the new ones were installed with the new disposal. The way the disposal attaches is a universal fit and your handyman just used used the existing flange and bracket which is why it corroded and split.  You can try and see what happens.